# Property 'value' does not exist on type

Tags: react-native, use-state

```
const [ selectedItem, setSelectedItem ] = useState<{ label?: string; value?: string }[]>();


      const getvalues = () => [
        {
          label : 'text',
          value : `${selectedItem?.value}` ---> here
        }
      ];
```

*This is work. However, it gives warning about 'Property 'value' does not exist on type  Did you mean 'values'. What should I do  ?*

Answer (score 1):

while selectedItem is an array so you cant access the value field directly but you should first get an item from the array then access its value field

```
  const getvalues = () => [
    {
      label : 'text',
      value : `${selectedItem?.[0].value}` // access first value of the first item
    }
  ];
```

the values suggested is the iterator object of the array values it doesnt have any relation with your object see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values